# php echo records from array grouped by specific record

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, grouping

I have two tables:

ROOMS 
room_id>>>room_name

```
1       foot massage
2       face massage
3       back massage
```

ORDERS 
room_id >>>start_date>>>>>>>end_date>>>>>>>>price

```
1       2012.09.10      2012.09.11      100
1       2012.09.11      2012.09.13      200
2       2012.11.11      2012.11.13      100
3       2012.12.11      2012.12.13      500
```

I want to out put results like this:

**room number 1:**

```
2012.09.10      2012.09.11      100
2012.09.11      2012.09.13      200
```

**room number 2:**

```
2012.11.11      2012.11.13      100
```

**room number 3:**

```
2012.12.11      2012.12.13      500
```

code:

```
$query_spa = "SELECT 
rooms.room_id,
rooms.room_name,
orders.start_date,
orders.end_date,
orders.price
FROM rooms
INNER JOIN orders
ON
 rooms.room_id =orders.room_id";

 $spa = mysql_query($query_spa, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
 $results = array();
 while($line = mysql_fetch_array($spa, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
$results[] = $line;
  }


  $groups = array();
 foreach($results as $item)
 $groups[$item['room_id']][] = $item;
  foreach($groups as $value => $items)
      echo 'room number ' . $value . ' : ' ;
for ($i=0; $i< count($items);$i++)
{
echo $items[$i]['start_date'] ;
echo $items[$i]['end_date'] ;
echo $items[$i]['price'] ;
}
```

outputs :

room number 1: room number 2: room number 3: 2012.12.11     2012.12.13      500

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this out:

```
$groups = array();
foreach($results as $item)
    $groups[$item['room_id']][] = $item;

foreach($groups as $value => $items)
{
    echo 'room number ' . $value . ' : ' ;
    foreach ($items as $item)
    {
        echo $item['start_date'] ;
        echo $item['end_date'] ;
        echo $item['price'] ;
    }
}
```

You can loop through sub-items with simple foreach. But better to make group sorting on fetching step:

```
while($line = mysql_fetch_array($spa, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $groups[$line['room_id']][] = $line;
}
```

So u got sorted result right after fetching.